# How to add filters so that I can group employees reporting to manager ?? Please guide me. Also let me know if the below code is correct or not

Tags: python, erp

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

"""reading url""" 
"""Creating the dataframe"""

urlData=requests.get(http://demo.rahierp.com/desk#List/Employee/List).content

df = pd.read_csv(io.StrigIO(urlData.decode('utf-8')))

 """Print the dataframe"""

 df

 """applying groupby() function to"""

"""group the data on reports_to"""

 gk = df.groupby('Reports To')

 gk


for Reports To,reports_to_df in gk:

print(Reports To)

print(reports_to_df)
```

Comment: Did you run the code? There're a lot of syntax errors. Show us an example of your results and what you expect the results should be.

Answer (score 0):

put column name (i.e.Reports_to )and the value of column on which you want filter result

```
df.loc[lambda df: df.Reports_to == 'John']
```

output

```
    name manager
  0 Orid     John
  1 David    John
```

Comment: Thank you @Snehal R Ghungurde. how do I do this for multiple managers.

Comment: print(df.loc[df['Reports_to'].isin(['John','MArk'])])

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehension -

```
print(df.loc[df['manager']=='LMN'])
```